# I am trying to consume elastic search API using Spring webflux to make my API endpoint Non blocking

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am creating an endpoint in Spring boot 2 and using Spring webflux. In this endpoint I will be taking Latitude and Longitude from the caller and will return state based on this. In order to get the state, I am calling elastic search API to get the data.

I am able to get the response from Elastic search API as below:

```
{
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 117252,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "geolocation",
        "_type": "geolocationdata",
        "_id": "AWt0m6GJqkN7DgSP9Lsd",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "network": "117.254.200.0/22",
          "geonameId": 1262062,
          "registeredCountrygeonameId": 1269750,
          "representedCountrygeonameId": "",
          "postalCode": "370655",
          "location": "23.2667,68.8333",
          "accuracyRadius": 100,
          "localecode": "en",
          "continentcode": "AS",
          "continentname": "Asia",
          "countryisocode": "IN",
          "countryname": "India",
          "subdivision1isocode": "GJ",
          "subdivision1nname": "Gujarat",
          "subdivision2isocode": "",
          "subdivision2nname": "",
          "cityName": "Naliya",
          "metroCode": "",
          "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
        },
        "sort": [
          6986.775031169917
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Once I have this JSON, I would like to get only necessary fields out of it and construct a model that is needed for my API and that will be returned to the caller.

Here is How I am consuming Elastic search API and getting the result

```
private WebClient webClient;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("http://172.24.5.162:9200/geolocation")
        .defaultHeader(
            HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build();
}

public String getGeoname(String latitude, String longitude) throws Exception {
    try {
        String req = "{\"from\": 0,\"size\": 1,\"sort\": {\"_geo_distance\": {\"location\": {\"lat\": " + latitude
                + ",\"lon\": " + longitude
                + "},\"order\": \"asc\",\"unit\": \"km\",\"distance_type\": \"plane\"}}}";

        final String test;

        //result from Elastic search API
        Mono<String> result = webClient.post()
                                 .uri("/_search")
                                 .body(Mono.just(req), String.class)
                                 .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception while sending request to Elastic search Lat: " + latitude + " Long: " + longitude, ex);
        return gson.toJson(new ErrorModel(ErrorCodes.BAD_INPUT, "Bad Input"));
    }
    return "";
}
```

In the result variable, I have the JSON as shown above as Mono. If I will use block() method on result variable to get the string which is the JSON IWant then it will block the main thread and will become blocking. My requirement is to consume this Mono so that I can do operation as below(Basically I am constructing GeoLocation my model)

```
String hits = "";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(o);

if (jsonObject.has("hits") && jsonObject.getJSONObject("hits").has("hits")) {
    hits = jsonObject.getJSONObject("hits")
        .getString("hits");

    hits = hits.substring(1);

    JSONObject hitsJson = new JSONObject(hits);
    JSONObject source = new JSONObject();
    if (hitsJson.has("_source")) {
        source = hitsJson.getJSONObject("_source");
        GeoLocation geolocation = new GeoLocation(source.getString("continentname"),
        source.getString("countryname"), 
        source.getString("subdivision1nname"),
        source.getString("cityName"));

        geoLocationResponse = Mono.just(gson.toJson(geolocation));
```

How do I above operation in a Non blocking fashion and return the result to my endpoint caller? I am thinking to return Mono from my RestController

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't use try catch in a reactive world, we create `Mono.error` and then act upon those errors later in the signal chain.

You should really check out some tutorials or try out the basic getting started in the reactor project documentation. It will help you a lot.

You should leverage jackson that comes bundled in spring boot instead of using JSONObject and Gson.

```
public Mono<GeoLocation> getGeoname(String latitude, String longitude) {
    final String req = "{\"from\": 0,\"size\": 1,\"sort\": {\"_geo_distance\": {\"location\": {\"lat\": " + latitude
                + ",\"lon\": " + longitude
                + "},\"order\": \"asc\",\"unit\": \"km\",\"distance_type\": \"plane\"}}}";

    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/_search")
            .body(Mono.just(req), String.class)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                // Check status if not 200 create a mono error that we will act upon later
                if(clientResponse.rawStatusCode() != 200)
                    return Mono.error(RuntimeException::new);
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
            }).map(body -> {

                // if you want to work with strings then do your mapping here
                // otherwise replace bodyToMono(FooBar.class) the FooBar class with a              
                // representation of the returned body and jackson will map to it.

                return new GeoLocation();
            }).doOnError(throwable -> {
                // handle the mono error we created earlier here, and throw an exception.
                // Then handle the exception later in a global exception handler
                throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
            });
}
```

Comment: What's your reference on not using try/catch? You can still return a Mono.error or let it bubble up the steam (if you can). Retrieve gives you a lot of niceties e.g. not having to manually check status codes

Comment: my reference is the documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling and https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.errors as soon as you use try catch you get outside of the reactive chain.

Comment: You still need to handle statuscodes with retrieve https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve exchange gives you the response object so you can check, with retrieve you have to use the built in methods to check. How you wish to do it is up to you, you still need to check status codes.

Comment: more on error handling https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_error_handling_operators

Comment: and yes you can let an error bubble up the stream if you wish too, its up to you